# Bootstrap navigation transparent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to make my navigation with help of bootstrap, and I can not make it transparent (see-through).

Here is my codepen for it:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akKYjZ

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
    border: none;
}
```

The funny thing is that I used this nav on my previous project and it is transparent there.

Hope you can help me out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  backckground-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes - you misspelled `background` in `background color`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZKvJv

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `.navbar-inverse` [belongs to Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). So instead of fighting with Bootstrap, just use your own class, like `.navbar-transparent`.

http://codepen.io/calebanth/pen/AXdyzG

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `opacity` property:

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    opacity: yourValue;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but this takes anchors as well, all I need is a background color of nav to be transparent.